# php why does TRUE == "expired"?

Tags: php, comparison, operators

This drove me nuts for a few hours.

I have a function returning one of the three following values:

```
function checkValid() {
   ...
   return array("expired",$oldDate,$newDate) ;
   return array(true,$oldDate,$newDate) ;
   return array(false,$oldDate,$newDate) ;
}

list($isValid,$oDate,$nDate) = checkValid() ;

if ($isValid == "expired") {
   ... 
   ...do blah
}
```

...and everytime the condition returned `true`, the `if ($isValid == "expired") { ... }` would trigger.   So I ran some tests and sure enough:

```
$isValid = true ;
if ($isValid == "expired") {
   echo "Yup...some how 'expired' equals TRUE" ;
} else {
   echo "Nope....it doesn't equal true" ;
}

output:  Yup...some how 'expired' equals TRUE
```

When I changed the if/condition to:

```
$isValid = true ;
if ($isValid === "expired") {
   echo "Yup...some how 'expired' equals TRUE" ;
} else {
   echo "Nope....it doesn't equal true" ;
}

output: Nope....it doesn't equal true
```

I am baffled by this.  Why would `true == 'expired'` or `1 == 'expired'` ???

Comment: Check this table: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types. Operand 1 in this case is bool `true`, so the string `"expired"` is converted to boolean for the comparison.

Comment: When converting a string to boolean, only an empty string and the string "0" evaluates as false. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @Don'tPanic - that is NUTS.  I thought I understood the concept of truthy, but that blew me away.  I think I made assumptions that JS truthy would also be the same as PHP truthy....but....nope.

Comment: Nope indeed. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using two equal signs `==` php does type coersion under the hood and checks for truthy cases which includes all numbers other than `0`, boolean `true`, all string other than empty strings and some other cases.

If you want to check for an exact match, you should use three equal signs `===`

Comment: I did resolve it by using `===` ...but I don't understand how even `true == 'expired'` is still considered truthy.  Still confused by it....esp compared to JS where this wouldn't happen ( I don't think)

Comment: It does happen in js and soloution is exactly the same, What php checks when types on both sides is different is type casting . So your string either becomes false or true.

Comment: If the string is empty or is 0 like "0" and maybe few other cases i guess then it evaluates to false otherwise to true

Comment: `type casting` - I will read up on that.  I just tested it in JS and it did not evaluate as true/ truthy.  `var a = true; if (a == "expired") { console.log("HERE") ; }` does not output HERE to the console.

Comment: @rolinger my bad you are right, but still javascript also has a truthy table https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ and this is for php https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: @PooyaEstkhri - I think maybe my understanding of JS truthy confused me with what my I expected PHP truthy to be.  Thats just downright ugly.  lol

Comment: Yeah so many developers wasted so many hours on this